# Do i need Virtual environment for lxml and beautiful soup in linux?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am doing a data scraping project in python.For that i need to use beautiful soup and lxml.Should i install them globally or in a virtual environment?

Comment: It doesn't matter. it will work in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Using or not using a virtual environment is up to you. But it is always a best practice to use `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`. So that if something unusual happens with your project and its dependencies it won't hamper the python reciding at the system level.

It might happen that in future you might need to work on different version of `lxml` or `beautifulsoup` and if you do not use virtual environment then you need to upgrade or degrade the libraries and now your older project will not run as you have upgraded or degraded everything in the system level python. Therefore it is wise to start using the best practices as early as possible to save time and efforts.

Comment: While installing lxml i also needed to install some libraries for compiling c in virtual environment.So whenever i set up a virtual environment do i need to download these libraries again and again? I am sorry if this is a trivial question as i am new to python and Linux.

Comment: all those libraries which are python libraries needed to be installed in virtualenv the system level libraries needed to be installed just once.

Answer (score 0):

That's a matter of personal preference, however in most cases the benefits of installing libraries in a virtual environment far outweigh the costs.

Setting up virtualenv (and perhaps virtualenvwrapper), creating an environment for your project, and activating it will take 2-10 minutes (depending on your familiarity with the system) before you can start work on your project itself, but it may save you a lot of hassle further down the line. I would recommend that you do so.